# Qt C++ read access violation Exception

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am working with a project with Qt and C++, and project uses multiple thread and extern global variable. The extern variable is accessing from different thread for reading and writing, where as there is no mutex implemented currently to read/write these variable.   Right now I am getting some exception while running the program and this is not happening every time but randomly.

These are some output from Qtcreator

```
Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 000000778A310000, 000000778E6AF5D0 )
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...AppStore-MSVC_X64\debug\App.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c
Line: 1322

Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
Debug Assertion Failed!


Program: ...AppStore-MSVC_X64\debug\App.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c
Line: 1328

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
```

Here is the screenshot after exception.

[image]

1. Is this happening because the extern variable are not thread safe?
2. Or due to variable uninitialized, but while debugging I can see the variable has some data.

## Edit

I cannot post the entire code here as the project contain lot of source code, but the situation is something like

**global.h**

```
extern QString outfilepath;
```

**main.cpp**

```
 QString outfilepath;
 ...................
 ...................
 outfilepath = somePath;
```

**thread1.cpp**

```
 ...................
 QString tmp1 = outfilepath;
 ...................
```

**thread2.cpp**

```
 ...................
 QString tmp2 = outfilepath;
 ...................
```

Comment: Let's get real: you're showing 4 statements, with no context, and expect us to figure out what's wrong? There are very few cases where it'd fly. Pretend that the code shown isn't yours, but mine. Would you be able to help me? Nope. So help us help you by showing a minimal, *self contained* test case that reproduces the issue. You'll learn a lot by producing such a test case. Start by duplicating your project and start throwing things away. Every statement and declaration whose removal  doesn't make the problem go away, should be removed.

Comment: My gut feeling is that you don't know enough to implement multithreading properly, but it's impossible to know what exactly you don't know :(

Comment: Number of possible error sources is astronomical. `outfilepath` may have been smashed by a rogue pointer or overflow. We can, however, rule out Ninjas.

Comment: @Kuba Ober See my edit. I just want know accessing extern variable from different thread without mutex could cause such an exception?.

Comment: @Harris It shouldn't cause problems as long as you guarantee that the string's value has been set before other threads access it, and as long as you guarantee that the string's value won't be changed. Ideally, you'd want `outfilepath` to be a `const QString`, and the threads started after it was constructed.

Comment: "I cannot post the entire code here as the project contain lot of source code" 99% of your code is irrelevant: you can remove it while maintaining the crash/exception. That's what minimization is all about. In most cases, while you're doing it, you'll find the bug yourself. Not doing it turns SO into an outsourced debugging service, and that's not what SO is for. A question has no place here if it the answer is only usable to you and nobody else. Seriously, try it. Copy your project to a new folder. Init a git repo there. Start cutting things and committing as you go. Enlightenment awaits :)

Answer (score 1):

By the exception message, I would say you are accessing an uninitialized object. Code `0xC0000005` means an access violation and a read address was at 0. It looks like you haven't initialized it.

The external variable should be accessible by both threads, but you should always protect data being accessed by multiple threads with a thread safe technique, such as the mutex you mention.